# OSX remote X app

Tags: macos, ubuntu, x-windows, workstation, xorg

Right now at work I have an Ubuntu workstation and I'm considering switching over to OSX but I have one major concern. I run Eclipse on our Ubuntu development server using a remote X session: basically I log into my server with `ssh -X` and then I launch eclipse and it pops open on my workstation and everything is great. When I do this from OSX (I tried with someone's laptop) the resulting window is really clunky, ugly and unresponsive.

Is there a better way to do this which will result in a smoother user experience?

Answer (score 0):

Use sshfs to mount whatever development file you need (if necessary) and use the Mac version of Eclipse.

The X11 version doesn't really work very well on Mac... (Menu and keyboard shortcuts, etc)

Comment: I don't think that's an option: Eclipse needs to be able to launch/compile apps on the server, as that's where all of our libraries etc are set up...

Comment: I really recommend you install the libraries and setup the development environment locally as doing everything through X-redirection is very inefficient. If you insist on doing it remotely, you may want to use VNC instead because the X protocol is not compressed and it only works well on LAN connections.

Comment: Installing libraries locally is not an option, unfortunately, and X has been working great so far as I am on a LAN... NoMachine X was an option until OSX Lion but now there's no non-PPC option for running NX :(